# Breaking the line

Tags: formatting, align

I have the following code:

```
    \listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\underline{Verwendete Bezeichnungen}

\begin{align*}
Q_{j,Standby}&: \text{ Standbyleistung des Ger{\"a}tes j} \\ 
Q_j(t_r) &: \text{ Leistung des Ger{\"a}tes j relativ zum Startzeitpunkt}\\ 
r_j &: \text{ Release-Zeitpunkt von Ger{\"a}t j} \\
 s_j &: \text{ Relativer Startzeitpunkt des Ger{\"a}tes j.HERE BREAK THE LINE Angegeben in Bezug auf den fr{\"u}hestmöglichen Startzeitpunkt} \\ 
t_r &: \text{ relative Zeit in Bezug auf den Startzeitpunkt des Ger{\"a}tes j } \\ 
t &: \text{ absolute Systemzeit} \\ 
\end{align*}



\end{document}
```

And I want to break the line at the s_j Line (I have pointed out the position where exactly I would like to break the line). When I use \  then I get many errors.

Comment: you can not break inside `\text` end that text, break with `\\ ` then start a new `\text` or use a multiline box such as `\parbox`

Comment: But what can I do to make the line start at the same position as the previous text line? If I add this comment: s_j &: \text{ Relativer Startzeitpunkt des Ger{\"a}tes j.} \\
 &\text{Angegeben in Bezug auf den fr{\"u}hestmöglichen Startzeitpunkt} \\  then it does not start at the right position

Answer (score 2):

You want a multi-line construct rather than `\text` for example `tabular` or `\parbox`

[image]

```
    \listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\underline{Verwendete Bezeichnungen}

\begin{align*}
Q_{j,Standby}&: \text{ Standbyleistung des Ger{\"a}tes j} \\ 
Q_j(t_r) &: \text{ Leistung des Ger{\"a}tes j relativ zum Startzeitpunkt}\\ 
r_j &: \text{ Release-Zeitpunkt von Ger{\"a}t j} \\
 s_j &: \text{ }\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
Relativer Startzeitpunkt des Ger{\"a}tes j.\\
Angegeben in Bezug auf den fr{\"u}hestmöglichen Startzeitpunkt\end{tabular} \\ 
t_r &: \text{ relative Zeit in Bezug auf den Startzeitpunkt des Ger{\"a}tes j } \\ 
t &: \text{ absolute Systemzeit} \\ 
\end{align*}



\end{document}
```

Comment: @PaulGessler fixed (in a way;-)

Comment: The 'j' particles to the right of the colons should be in math mode.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure contains far more text that math; I would just set it using a `center` environment (for horizontal alignment) and use a `tabular` for structure:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\underline{Verwendete Bezeichnungen}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{r@{~:~}l}
    $Q_{j,\text{Standby}}$ & Standbyleistung des Ger{\"a}tes~$j$ \\
         $Q_j(t_r)$ & Leistung des Ger{\"a}tes~$j$ relativ zum Startzeitpunkt \\
              $r_j$ & Release-Zeitpunkt von Ger{\"a}t~$j$ \\
              $s_j$ & Relativer Startzeitpunkt des Ger{\"a}tes~$j$. \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & Angegeben in Bezug auf den fr{\"u}hestmöglichen Startzeitpunkt\\
              $t_r$ & relative Zeit in Bezug auf den Startzeitpunkt des Ger{\"a}tes~$j$ \\
                $t$ & absolute Systemzeit \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's `\multicolumn{1}{l}{}` for?

Comment: @egreg: To remove the column-separation colon. Of course, it might not be necessary.